# Change variable based on indexPath.row

Tags: swift, xcode, collectionview

I have four different variables, called `display0, display1, display2, display3`.  I then have a collectionView, with a reusable cell that has a textLabel inside it. There will be four cells, whose textLabels I want to set to `display1 through to display4`. Can I do something along the lines of `cell.textLabel.text = display\(indexPath.row)`?

Thanks.

Comment: Use an array instead `var display = ["", "", "", ""]`. Then you can access with `display[indexPath.row]`.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't infer variable name from concatenation at run time meaning that if you have a variable declared like

```
var display0 = "5"
```

then if you did

```
let str = "display\(indexPath.row)"
```

str will have a string `display0` but won't have the actual content inside the variable `display0` as both are irrelevant cases

Either :

1- Add them to the model array

```
var arr = ["contentvar1","contentvar2","contentvar3","contentvar4"]

cell.textLabel.text = arr[indexPath.row]
```

2- Use a switch case

```
switch indexPath.row  {
 case 0 :
      cell.textLabel.text = display0
  ---
}
```

Option 1 is more efficient than 2

Answer (score 0):

create a list of variables :

```
let displays = ["data0","data1","data2","data3"]
```

you can simply assign variable or change them:

```
displays[1] = "newData1"
```

then in your cellForRow just call this:

```
cell.textLabel.text = displays[indexPath.row]
```

Comment: How does this improve on the information provided in the other answer? Please don't post duplicate answers.